# How to run Ratchet remotely or on a server?

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io, ratchet

Everything works fine on my local machine on XAMPP. But after I uploaded the files to a server, it gives a error like this...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'React\Socket\ConnectionException' with message 'Could not bind to tcp://0.0.0.0:8080: Address already in use' in 
/home/sites/jemaottest.com/public_html/websocket/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php:29 Stack trace: #0 
/home/sites/jemaottest.com/public_html/websocket/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/IoServer.php(70): React\Socket\Server->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0') #1 
/home/sites/jemaottest.com/public_html/websocket/bin/chat-server.php(17): Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(Object(Ratchet\Http\HttpServer), 8080, '0.0.0.0') #2 {main} thrown in 
/home/sites/jemaottest.com/public_html/websocket/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php on line 29
```

when I run the chat-server.php file.

I found out something on the troubleshooting page of Ratchet which says,

> If you want to open Ratchet up (not behind a proxy) set the third parameter of App to '0.0.0.0'.

I tried that but it didn't work,

```
<?php 
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080,
    '0.0.0.0'
);

$server->run();  
?>
```

it still gave the same error.

What should I do now?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I'm having the same issue and I don't find anything

Answer (score 2):

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
new HttpServer(
    new WsServer(
        new Chat()
    )
),
8282
```

);

Just Change the port and try.. mine is works fine after changing my port. And also don't forget to change the port in your port in websocket javascript class too.

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://yourdomain.com:8282');
```

Answer (score 1):

I later found out using other ports are not allowed on a shared server.

If you are on a private server with a ssh access, you can try MarshallOfSound's solution.

Or if you just need the websocket as a service you can use something like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It means that nother process is running on port 8080.  Probably a webserver of some kind.

You can find out what is running with the command

```
lsof -i :8000
```

You can either stop the process already using the port.  Or run Ratchet on a different port.

Comment: I tried it with many other ports, but it still gave same error.
Do I have to give the ip address of the server in place of '0.0.0.0'. (I am confused, nothings' working)